# index field in ravenDB which contains dots

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I'd like to index a field within a ravenDB document which contains dots in it.

my document looks like the following:

```
  {
  "Headers": {
    "Foo.Bar.Message": "myMessage",
    "Foo2": "myMessage2"
  }
  }
```

the mapping index:

```
    from doc in docs.DocumentName
select new { Message = doc.Headers.Foo.Bar.Message, Message2 = Headers.Foo2 };
```

Unfortunately the dot separated field Headers.Foo.Bar.Message is not indexed because of the dots. the dots are probably handled as sub documents.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the indexer syntax:

```
from doc in docs.DocumentName
select new { Message = doc.Headers["Foo.Bar.Message"], Message2 = Headers.Foo2 };
```